# ssh command not working on juniper router

Tags: ssh, juniper

I'm trying to use ssh command on my MX juniper router but i get the following-error
-cli: unable to execute ssh: No such file or directory

this is the command i'm using:
ssh 10.27.1.2 source 10.53.3.150

Please help
Thanks

Comment: most likely means ssh is not installed or the path to it is not in the PATH environment variable!?!

Comment: how can i install ssh on a router? is it the same thing as doing it on a computer?

Comment: Your router is a computer. We will not be able to guide you through this process because you apparently do not understand the very basics. So google about the specifications and the operating system of your router and then you will probably know whether it is capable to issue ssh commands or how you can install software on it to make it possible. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for this:

1) You are running JunOS Worldwide, which does not support encryption and as such will not have the SSH client (or servers for that matter) installed.

2) You are running Junos Domestic which DOES support encryption, but the package is corrupted.

Solutions:

1) Upgrade from Junos Worldwide to Junos Domestic

2) Reinstall Junos to restore the package OR turn on FTP services and copy the missing packages from another extracted download and replace the corrupted files in the filesystem.

EDIT:

Option 3: Call JTAC and make them fix it :)